# Decompress large binary files

Tags: java, compression, gzip, binaryfiles

I have a function to decompress large zip files using the below method. They are times where I run into `OutOfMemoryError` error because the file is just too large. Is there a way I can optimize my code? I have read something about breaking the file into smaller parts that can fit into memory and decompress but I don't know how to do that. Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

```
private static String decompress(String s){
        String pathOfFile = null;

        try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(s)), Charset.defaultCharset()))){
            File file = new File(s);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

            String line;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                fos.write(line.getBytes());
                fos.flush();
            }

            pathOfFile = file.getAbsolutePath();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return pathOfFile;
    }
```

The stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.base/java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3689)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:237)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacity(ArrayList.java:217)
```

Comment: You are using `s` for both in and out file, that won't work. You can't write tot the same file you are reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `Reader` classes because you don't need to write output file character by character or line by line. You should read and write `byte` by `byte` with [`InputStream.transferTo()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#transferTo-java.io.OutputStream-) method:

```
try(var in = new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(inFile));
    var out = new FileOutputStream(outFile)) {
    in.transferTo(out);           
}
```

Also you probably don't need to call `flush()` explicitly, doing it after every line is wasteful.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. This is java 8+ syntax with var?

Comment: Java 10+ syntax

Comment: The system I'm working on is on Java 7. I did give this code a test on my personal machine which uses Java 11

Comment: Than you can't even use `transferTo` as it's Java 9+. See how it's implemented in [OpenJDK](https://github.com/unofficial-openjdk/openjdk/blob/f4373cbc91b948b74374a6751ab57a3827aa5bba/src/java.base/share/classes/java/io/InputStream.java#L776)

Comment: The Java 7 compatible alternative is not more complicated: `try(GZIPInputStream in = new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(inFile))) { Files.copy(in, Paths.get(outFile)); }` The method [`Files.copy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.io.InputStream-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) exists since Java 7. In this specific case, it might be the preferred solution even for newer versions, as it’s not necessary to deal with the target `OutputStream` manually.